# Use gulp.js for Shopify theme deployment via Shopify CLI and to GitHub

Tags: git, gulp, shopify

I'm using the Shopify CLI for local theme development, and Gulp for automation. This is my first experience with both, so it's a bit of a learning experience.

I'd like to use Gulp to handle the `shopify theme push` command, but haven't been able to make it work yet.

The end goal, if possible, is to set up a single Gulp task that will `git commit` (prompting for the commit message), then push to my GitHub repository, then push to my Shopify store.

Is this beyond the scope of Gulp? It seems there ought to be a way to do this, but as I said, I'm just starting to figure out what it can do.

Comment: Why are you trying to automate something that really, needs no automation? Is this some kind of work avoidance tactic? if you are developing a theme, should you not be spending your hours on that and not on trying to save typing git push? I mean, to each their own, but this seems like a crazy use of gulp to save typing 8 keystrokes once in a while.

Comment: I'm new to Gulp and was trying to develop a single command that would do various launch tasks all at once, including some not mentioned in my original post. It's really more about learning Gulp's capabilities and how to use them though.

Answer (score 0):

You could spawn a node child process to run the `shopify theme push` command:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child = spawn('shopify', ['theme', 'push']);

child.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log('stdout:\n');
  console.log(data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.log('stderr:\n');
  console.log(data);
});
```

Chaining the steps should definitely be in the scope of gulp.